# Reduce column spacing for bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having this issue where I am trying to reduce the column length of only large screens. For large screens, I have my div class as so:

`<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="vertical-align: middle;>Selected Fields</div>`

But on large screens (when `col-lg-2` takes precedent), it seems as if the spacing of the word Selected Fields is too much. Is there any way I can "hardcode" the size of the column when we are dealing with large screens? This is an example of what it looks like, where the spacing to the right of the "Selected Fields" image is the culprit.
[image]

And as we can see, the Selected Fields is extremely distant from the Account:Account Balance image. It seems like only for large screens I get this issue. I tried to follow this link: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/bootstrap-3-tips-and-tricks-you-still-might-not-know which was the closet thing I could find and added `padding-right:0;` and `padding-left:0;` in a style tag but that didn't seem to fix anything: that only changes the padding within a row. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is space on left side of that div problem?

Comment: @NenadVracar it's spacing on the right side of the word "Selected Fields."

Comment: You can set the width of that div in media queries > 1200px. And next time provide your code so you can get better answers.

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry about that. I will provide more next time... where can I go to learn how to set the width of that div in media queries > 1200 px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this css at end of your css file or in your separate queries.css file if you created one

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { //Here you specify on what device width you want this css to apply. So this will be applied on >1200 width
  .yourDiv {
      width: 150px; //You will write your own data here of course :)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a housekeeping tip, as the question is already answered by Nenad, however it may save you some time in future, as well as keeping your markup more concise.

Bootstrap column sizes work upwards, meaning you don't need to repeat your column sizes for every breakpoint if they don't change.

This means that your div column classes:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">...</div>
```

can be shortened to:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-3">...</div>
```

as col-md and col-sm inherit their size from col-xs.

You have also forgotten to close your style tag:

```
... style="vertical-align: middle;">
```